# CSS - There is a random whitespace between 2 divs

Tags: css

I'm having trouble with my styling. This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
  html,
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }

  #header {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #menu {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #B81F00;
  }

  #menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 15vw;
    line-height: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    /*border: black solid 1px;*/
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }

  #menu a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #7B1700;
  }

  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 600px) {
    #menu a {
      background-color: #B81F00;
      float: center;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 20px;
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 20px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #menu {
      position: relative;
      padding-top: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
      height: auto;
    }
  }
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    <a href="#">
      <p>Section1</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Section2</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Section3</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>Section4</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now, when I open it in mobile viewpoint, I get this:
[image: problem]

As you can see, there is a little whitespace between those two elements, but I can't figure out what caused this.

Comment: Could you please add your code html and css code in your post

Comment: We expect a [mcve] in the post itself. You can add a stack snippet by clicking the `<>` button.

Comment: There is a  whitespace in your code between <div id="header"> and <div id="menu"> ...

Comment: There is also no such thing as `float: center;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [White Space in Middle of HTML Page Won't Go Away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770719/white-space-in-middle-of-html-page-wont-go-away)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The P elements have a margin, you should remove it. Use padding instead.

```
#menu a p {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0;
}
```

If you want to center the content of the P perfectly try to use flex-box.